# Connecting phone via usb is a mess Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: usb, android, 17.04, connection, mtp

When I try connecting my Asus Zenfone 2 to my ubuntu 17.04 via usb, nothing seems to work properly. First, it gets detected and gets open. I can see internal and sd card of the phone, I can enter both. But from there, If I open a folder in my phone, The ubuntu hangs. If I remove the phone, May be the system comes back alive. If I try connecting the phone again, the phone doesnt even show the option to connect. It just sits there and gets charged. Thats all.

My brother's Moto G4 is not detected when connected.

It is a mess. I have installed mtp. Please help
Thanks

Comment: MTP is a messy and slow protocol which is why I use FTP to transfer files wirelessly between android and my PC. There are tons of apps on android which provide an FTP server. ES file explorer is quite popular and easy to use. Then, you can use the curl command on the linux computer to upload files to the phone or you can use your webbrowser or wget to download files from the phone to the linux computer. Data transfer rate is at least 10 to 100 times better over wifi compared to USB.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a little app, that starts an ssh server on any android phone: **SSHelper from Paul Lutus** ( available at Playstore ).

With this app you will see your phone in "other locations" or you can login  manually, access certain directories and create bookmarks e.g. via:

```
sftp://ip_of_your_phone:2222/sdcard
sftp://ip_of_your_phone:2222/storage/whatever
```

This works very well and with a speedy wlan very fast and wireless ;-)

If you have trouble: uninstall the app and reinstall it. This will recreate a new server key. Also you should change the Passord (it defaults to "admin").

I am using this for syncing certain content with rsync (unison) between my phone and my pc which works very well. If you do this, you can use the gvfs-link

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp\:host\=YOUR_IP\,port\=2222/YOUR_SUB_DIR_ON_ANDROID
```

for syncing on the phone's side.

Cheers
Axel

BTW: Yes, totaly agree: mtp sucks!